# Finding the digits in base $26$

Tags: decimal-expansion

Let $s = (s_0, \dots, s_k)$ with $0 \leq s_i \leq 25 \ \forall i$, and $f(s) = s_0 26^0 + s_1 26^1 + s_2 26^2 + \dots + s_{k-1} 26^{k-1}$.

Is it possible, and if so how, to find all the $s_i$ knowing $f(s)$?

For example, if $s = (4, 1, 2, 3)$ then $f(s) = 4 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 26 + 2 \cdot 676 + 3 \cdot 17576 = 54110$. How would one go about finding all the $s_i : 4, 1, 2, 3$ from $f$ and its result $54110$?

Ps: I'm a bit of a math novice, so I'd appreciate a "noob friendly" version of an answer.

Comment: Your post was quite confusing, so I have edited it to clarify its meaning. Despite my best efforts, it is possible that I might have betrayed your intentions, so please check whether my changes still convey what you meant. The current title is not the best, but is clearly better than the original one.

Comment: Ah, sorry about my confusing formulation. Yes, your changes still convey what I meant, thanks for the editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recall the algortihm for compuing the *decimal* digits of a natural $\rm \,n.$

Let $\rm \,D(n)\,$ be the list of digits of $\rm\,n\,$ and let $\,\sqcup\,$ denote list concatenation.

By division $\rm\, n = 10 q + r\ $ for $\rm \,r = n\bmod 10,\ $ where $\rm \ 0\le r < 10$

Hence $\rm \, D(n) = D(q) \sqcup [r],\, $ which leads to the following algorithm

$\qquad\ \ \  \begin{align} \text{D(n) := }& \text{if  $\rm \ n < 10\ $ then $\rm \,[\,n\,]$}\\
&\text{else let $\rm \{\,r = n\bmod 10;\ \  q = (n\!-\!r)/10\,\}$}\\
&\qquad\ \ \rm D(q)\sqcup [\,r\,]
\end{align}$

The above algorithm works for any radix $\rm\,b\,$ by replacing $\,10\,$ by $\rm \,b\,$ above.

Comment: this in combination with the answer from @Takahiro Waki now makes total sense.. about time I understood how these 'base switches' worked, thanks!

Comment: @darthDoe Yes, that is the same algorithm (except it is not presented in recursive form there).

Answer (score 1):

Try with smaller basis - 2,8,10,... The algorithm will be analogous, for example:

$s_0 = f(s) (\mod 26^1) $

$s_1 = (f(s) - s_026^0)(\mod 26^2) $

...

$s_n =  \left(f(s)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s_k 26^{k}\right)(\mod 26^{n+1})$

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand this correctly, but if, like in the example $s=(4,1,2,3)$ and $f(s) = 5411054110$ then my $s_0$ should be $5411054110 \mod 26^1$ but that equals $20$ and not $4$?

Comment: $f((4,1,2,3))=54110$, $54110(\mod 26) = 4$

Comment: Oh wow, I accidentally pasted the result in twice. Thanks!

Comment: @darthDoe Beware that there is a bug above (you need to cancel $26^i$ to get $\,s_i).\, $ See my answer for a natural recursive algorithm to compute the digits in any radix.

Comment: @BillDubuque Could you elaborate the bug?

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for pointing that out, I thought I was going crazy for not getting to the right result. Although I have to admit I still don't understand what you mean by "cancel $26^i$ to get $s_i$".

Comment: @darthDoe The above gives $\,s_i 26^i\,$ so if you want $\,s_i\,$ you need to cancel/divide by $\,26^i.\,$ It is more efficient to use the method I describe if you want all of the digits.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks alot, this approach works now.. at last. I'm still trying to wrap my head around your answer bellow.

Comment: @darthDoe Great. If you need some elaboration on the other method let me know what parts are not clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is like this. The example 231 base 4.

[image]